# Spring Boot application.properties lifecyle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I have a large Spring web application, dating back several years. I need to update it to Spring Boot (corporate requirement). I'm well on my way - it starts (!), although there are some issues with properties being injected, which causes the app to fail.

Specifically, there are three huge config files per profile, eg `qa_config.properties`, `qa_ehcache.xml`, `qa_monitoring.properties`. At present I only care about `qa_config.properties`, which I have renamed to Spring Boot's preferred name, `application-qa.properties`, and `application-qa_monitoring.properties`

The application has a number of classes annotated with `@Named` (from the javax.ws.rs-api ) which are loaded early - so early that I need to inject properties in the constuctor:

```
package com.domain.app;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
public class Foo {

    // Cant use @Value here, it is not yet in the context
    protected String bar; // lives in application-qa.properties
    protected String qux; // lives in application-qa_monitoring.properties

    public Foo(@Value("${application.property.named.bar}") String bar,
        @Value("${monitoring.property.named.qux}") String qux) {

        this.bar = bar;
        this.qux = qux;

        doSomeWork();

    }
}
```

Properties files:

```
#application-qa.properties
application.property.named.bar=something
```

and

```
#application-qa_monitoring.properties
monitoring.property.named.qux=another_thing
```

My problem: I want to have both `application-qa.properties` and `application-qa_monitoring.properties` in context as soon as possible, and *before* the `@Named` classes are loaded.

To achieve this, I am running the application with an active profile of `qa`, which successfully adds that set of properties into the context.

I added this line to the `application.properties` file, to ensure that the other properties are loaded:

```
spring.profiles.include=${spring.profiles.active}_monitoring.properties
```

When I run the Spring Boot app, the output tells me

```
The following profiles are active: qa_monitoring.properties,qa
```

When debugging the `Foo` class, the value of `bar` is correct

But, the value of `qux` is null.

Am I missing something about the order in which properties files are loaded? I would have thought that the `include` line in `application.properties` would be sufficient to "flatten" the two files very early on, if one is in context, so both should be available?

What I could do instead is just throw all the vars in the two properties files into one, the `application-qa.properties` but I'd like, if possible, to keep them seperate and as close to the original structure as possible.

Comment: When you specify `spring.profiles.include=${spring.profiles.active}_monitoring.properties` spring will search for a file `application-qa_monitoring.properties`, which it cannot find and hence the properties are not loaded

Comment: I actually made a copy of the file and named it `application-qa_monitoring.properties` - but this, too, does not work.

But you make a very good point. I will amend the question.

Comment: Remove the ".properties" off the end of your profile name. Right now it's trying to load qa_monitoring.properties.properties

Comment: Andy Brown has it right. pvpkiran was almost right - it became clear after his comment that the problem was between screen and chair, but Andy was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to pvpkiran and Andy Brown.

My application.properties file should have read

```
spring.profiles.include=${spring.profiles.active}_monitoring
```

ie, just adding another `profile`, in this case `qa_monitoring` - Spring automagically adds the `application-` prefix and the `.properties suffix`

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is because you use a literal value instead of a lookup key in the @Value annotation of your qux value.

Replace

```
    public Foo(@Value("${application.property.named.bar}") String bar,
    @Value("monitoring.property.named.qux") String qux) {
```

With

```
    public Foo(@Value("${application.property.named.bar}") String bar,
    @Value("${monitoring.property.named.qux}") String qux) {
```

And it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately that was simply an anonymising error. Will edit the question